# `getElementById` doesn’t find elements inside `<template>` tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-template

I want to add `<li>` to `<ul>` tag via JavaScript:

```js
const newLI = document.createElement("LI");
const ul = document.getElementById("tag_list");

ul.appendChild(newLI);
newLI.innerHTML = "<a href=\"dddaaaa\">" + json + "</a>";
```

```html
<template id="box#add-feeds">
  <ul class="search-ac" id="tag_list" name="tag_list"></ul>
</template>
```

When I remove the `<template>` tag, this code works well, but with this tag I have this error:

> `TypeError`: Cannot call method '`appendChild`' of `null`

I can’t remove the `<template>` tag so I have to change the JavaScript code. Any idea about why `getElementById` doesn’t find an element if it’s in a `<template>` tag?

Comment: Relevant documentation: [`<template>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<template` tag](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) is not a custom tag; it's a new HTML5 feature.

The whole point of `<template>` tags is that they aren't actually in the document.
That includes IDs.

You can examine or manipulate the contents of the template using the `content` property of the `<template>` tag's DOM element.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to access the content of a template?  where do I start?  I mean, where do I get the reference of a template tag in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Templates are there for you to **CLONE** them.

Given this HTML code:

```
<template id="add-feeds">
    <ul class="search-ac" id="tag_list" name="tag_list"></ul>
</template>
```

if you try something like this, it will *NOT* work (will return `null`):

```
var ul = document.getElementById('tag_list'); // ul is *null*
```

**THE WAY TO GO IS:**

**clone** the template (think about it of *instantiating a class*).

Let me add a `div` to your base html:

```
<template id="add-feeds">
    <ul class="search-ac" id="tag_list" name="tag_list"></ul>
</template>

<div id="show_list"></div>   //div used as DOM-entry-point for our new created list
```

Now clone the template:

```
var template= document.querySelector("#add-feeds");
my_template_clone = template.content.cloneNode(true); // clone the template 
var my_ul = my_template_clone.getElementById('tag_list'); //now you can find the *ul*

var newLI = document.createElement("LI"); //create random stuff
newLI.innerHTML="hello";
my_ul.appendChild(newLI);  //append it to the ul

var div = document.getElementById('show_list'); 
div.appendChild(my_ul); //now add it into the DOM
```

Here you have a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7npz84w/19/)