# Why sometimes code in js document doesn't work but in browser console it works perfectly fine?

Tags: javascript, foreach, console

I've a bunch os `<li>` and inside it I've a button that closes the li when clicked.

`.forEach` does not work in index.js, but only in the Chrome console. I can conclude that the code is error free, so what the heck?

The HTML

```html
<li draggable="true" class="draggable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" class="completed-input">
    <input type="text" class="new-task-input" placeholder="your todo...">
    <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
</li>
```

The JS

```
const btnsDelete = document.getElementsByName('close-outline')
btnsDeleteArray.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        containerAllTasks.removeChild(e.target.parentNode)
        removeKeyByValue(e.target.parentNode.children[1].value)
        countAllItems()
    })
})
```

I tried to convert it to a usual Array instead a NodeList

```
const btnsDelete = document.getElementsByName('close-outline')
const btnsDeleteArray = Array.from(btnsDelete)

btnsDeleteArray.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        containerAllTasks.removeChild(e.target.parentNode)
        removeKeyByValue(e.target.parentNode.children[1].value)
        countAllItems()
    })
})
```

I just want to run the code inside this `forEach` every time a certain button is clicked

Comment: Are the `close-outline` elements part of the DOM when the script runs? Where on the page do you include this script?

Comment: as @Ivar mentioned try adding your entire code inside of this block: 
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // your code ...
}, false);`
this would wait for the html content to be ready before executing your JS

Comment: when you run some js code on console any element of your page are already loaded in the DOM. That's not the same case when you put js code in a page. Look at `defer` property. Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design

Comment: @Ivar They are. And I've tried both ways of including the script - putting it at the top of the page with the defer and at the end of the page, it didn't work either.

Comment: @jollyjoyce1995 I use defer and then I tried to put it at the bottom... no difference.

I've a ton of other functions, woudn't it bug everything?

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can't tell why your script doesn't work. You can add `console.log(btnsDeleteArray.length)` to double check if if these elements can be found. (If the length is `0`, then these elements are not part of the DOM.)

Comment: @Ivar I have it hosted: https://gustavo361.github.io/todo-app/

I haven't finished yet so there's a lot of dead code there. This function starts at the 158° line.

if you wanna use it, use the mobile version, please.

the js file itself - https://github.com/Gustavo361/todo-app/blob/main/js/index.js

Comment: @Gustavo361 On that page, the elements [are in fact not part of the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbmxC.png). 5 of the `name="close-outline"` that appear on that page are commented out. The other one is part of a `<template>` element [and as such is not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156857/getelementbyid-doesn-t-find-elements-inside-template-tag).

Comment: @Ivar OH.. but it shouldn't be a problem because they will be created and then the  function should be activated and then look for the elements... weird

I need create the li from the template, but if I do that, I won't work. Do you know some solution?

Comment: Maybe it _should_ but it doesn't now. Currently the code runs when the `index.js` is loaded and that's it. If you want it to run after the elements are created, then you should run the code when that happens. Or you could look into [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript).

Comment: @Ivar I tried to make the forEach directly when calling the element in the js, not working. But thank you man, I appreciate your help a lot